# Method that has an array and has another number

Tags: java, arrays, search, methods

```
public static boolean mystery(int[] array, int target) {
   for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      if(array[i] == target) 
         return true;
      else if(array[i] > target)
         return false;
   }
   return false;
}
```

`int a[] = {2,5,11,14,15,27,31}`

1) What does mystery1(a,5) return?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVaDQ.jpg)

So this is my friend’s work.  My question pertains to question #1.  It takes in the array and target would equal 5.  So for i = 0 for the first loop in the for loop, it would return false, wouldn’t it?  It would only return true when  i = 1 so it would be a = 5 and target = 5 and return true.  But once it loops again because of “i++” wouldn’t it return false in the end?  Because he put true but I’m not sure if I got it wrong or he did.  Not too sure how this runs

Comment: Please transcribe the question instead of just an image.

Comment: Provide code here. The links should be an accessory, not a necessity.

Comment: I'm sorry; I'm new to the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does indeed return true.

The first time array[i] is 2 so it is not true. However it is also not greater (>) that the target (5) so the loop continues.

The second loop the array[i] is equal to the target so it returns true.

*For clarification*

The array looks like this. {2,5,11,14,15,27,31}.
The first iteration of the loop takes array[i] (i is 0) which gives number 2. So the condition is not true. The second condition is also not true since 2 is smaller than the target which is 5.

The second time it takes array[i] (i is 1) which gives number 5. That means the condition is true and the method return true.

Ps. You forgot to add the array used in the method (I looked at it from the pic).

Answer (score 0):

The answer is indeed **true**.

The method searches for the target and will only return **false** if the element from the current iteration is larger then the target or the iteration reaches the end of the array.

Since the array is ordered, you cannot have larger elements as the target before the target. So, as soon as the loop reaches the target it returns **true**, but if the array does not contain it, i.e reaches the end of the array or finds a larger number as the target, it returns **false**.

In your case: the target is in the array, so the result is **true**.